# Spark SQL - insert data into hive table from another hive table error

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I want to insert data into hive table from another hive table using Spark SQL. I am getting below error.

My code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GetHiveTableData");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaHiveContext hiveCtx = new JavaHiveContext(sc);

JavaSchemaRDD rdd = hiveCtx.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE table1 ( aggregation_date, subnetwork,last_5_max) select to_date(now()), subnetwork, max(last_5_minute_cpu_utilization_kpi)  from table2 where to_date(dataset_date)= to_date(now()) GROUP BY subnetwork");
```

Error msg:

```
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:83 cannot recognize input near '(' 'aggregation_date' ',' in select clause
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:161)
```

Comment: Are ( aggregation_date, subnetwork,last_5_max) your partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using valid hive syntax.  You need to do

```
insert into table table1 select ..
```

Hive uses :

- CTAS (create table as select)
- Load data (local) inpath

for creating data.

Comment: I tried using query:   insert into table tab3 select id2,col_12,col_22,col_32,0 from tab2  it worked in hive shell but didn't work from spark    JavaSchemaRDD rdd = hiveCtx.sql("insert into table tab3 select id2,col_12,col_22,col_32,0 from tab2");            getting error msg:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unsupported language features in query: insert into table tab3 select id2,col_12,col_22,col_32,0 from tab2

Comment: same query (insert into table tab3 select id2,col_12,col_22,col_32,0 from tab2) working fine in hive command line. then what is the correct syntax to use with sparkSQL?

Comment: Oh my bad: your syntax is fine. Somehow I misread it.  Actually let me look at the spark syntax parser now.

Comment: Can you try your query without the 0 literal? Or maybe replace the 0 literal with one other column (just for testing)  maybe that is tripping it up.

Comment: thanks for your replay....I tried query:  insert into table tab3 select id2,col_1,col_2,col_3 from tab2 but no luck. please let me know if need to do any configuration

Comment: below syntax not supported in Spark 1.x. and i updated my spark to 1.2 and below syntax working fine  insert into table tab3 select id2,col_12,col_22,col_32,0 from tab2  not

Answer (score 0):

Named insert in not supported in hive. Use this. it assumes that  table **table1** have one three columns in order **aggregation_date, subnetwork,last_5_max**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table1 select to_date(now()), subnetwork, max(last_5_minute_cpu_utilization_kpi)  from table2 where to_date(dataset_date)= to_date(now()) GROUP BY subnetwork;
```